# Calling FindViewById from Handler thread - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

So, I am trying to implement a simple timer in my application wherein I increment the MM:SS display every one second.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


        handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new GameActivity();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000); //Start Incrementing timer after 5s.

    }

@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String time = (String) timeView.getText();

        if (TimerUtilities.convertMSToSeconds(time) < R.integer.TimeLimit) 
        {
            time = TimerUtilities.incrementOne(time);
            timeView.setText(time);
            timeView.postInvalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(new GameActivity(), 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            time = TimerUtilities.incrementOne(time);
            timeView.setText(time);            
        }               
    }
```

When I looked at the logcat output - I am getting a null pointer exception in the findViewById line of the overridden run method.

So could the problem because of reading/updating UI from the handler thread. If so, is there an alternative way for me to do this ?

Comment: Is that overridden run() method from GameActivity class or you have implemented Runnable in you activity? Please make it clear

Comment: Yes, I have implemented Runnable in my Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run method is being called on the new GameActivity that you created. The setContentView method never gets called on it so it doesn't have any views. You probably wanted to call

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
```

instead of creating a new activity.